# D3 svg, Substring text if its larger then container

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I am appending some text to a svg `<g>` element. That `<g>` element does have *width* attribute. So, is there a way to substring content of a `<text>` element if its larger then its parent (g) ?

I tried with a way to limit text to e.g. 20 characters, but that doesn't always look good since characters are different.

Comment: `<g>` elements don't have width attributes. You can add one but it won't do anything.

Comment: I see. Also have `<rect>` inside that `<g>` who has valid width but `<text>` cannot be appended to a rect. So is there any kind of a trick how can I do this thing ?

Comment: A `<g>` element always autosizes to its content

Comment: You could use textLength, which would clinch the text to the desired length.. or use a clip to hide/cutoff the overflow.